# Setup Citus extension in a ssh environment

Tags: psql, citus

I tried to do `CREATE EXTENSION citus;`. However, I was given the following error:

```
ERROR:  Citus can only be loaded via shared_preload_libraries
HINT:  Add citus to shared_preload_libraries configuration variable in postgresql.conf in master and workers. Note that citus should be at the beginning of shared_preload_libraries.
```

However, I do not have root access. How can I create the extension in this case?

I am using PSQL's source code for setting up the database. Is there a specific file in here that I can modify to allow for the extension?

Here are the list of files in my `postgresql-15.3` source code folder:

```
COPYRIGHT    GNUmakefile.in  INSTALL   README      config      config.status  configure.ac  doc
GNUmakefile  HISTORY         Makefile  aclocal.m4  config.log  configure      contrib       src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to "modify root" (whatever you mean by that) to change `shared_preload_libraries`. All you need is either shell access to the PostgreSQL server as PostgreSQL user, so that you can modify `postgresql.conf`, or a database connection as superuser, so that you can modify the parameter with `ALTER SYSTEM`.

If you have neither shell access to the server nor superuser access, then you cannot use the extension.

Note that you need to restart PostgreSQL if you want the changed setting to take effect.

Comment: When I search for help, I was told that I need to modify `postgresql.conf`, which is done by`sudo nano /etc/postgresql/<version>/main/postgresql.conf`. I didn't know that the postgreSQL database also contained a `postgresql.conf`. Thank you for the help.

Comment: That *is* the `postgresql.conf` file of the database cluster. There should be only one.